# Is a sprinkler/pest question on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/55/how-do-i-prevent-critters-from-chewing-my-sprinkler-system) question was asked a few moments ago, and I am really tempted to click close as off topic, but since we are new here I wanted to check in with Meta.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I see no reason why pest control questions (whether varmints or insects) shouldn't be on-topic *in the context of a gardening or landscaping question*. In this case, he's asking about keeping them off his irrigation system, which sounds pretty on-topic to me.

Obviously, something like "How can I kill the mice in my walls?" or "How can I get rid of the bedbugs in my bed?" would be off-topic. Similarly, "How can I keep moths from nesting in my plenum-space fire sprinklers?" would be out of bounds.

Answer (score 15):

I think it's on topic.  Full disclosure though, it's my question. :)

The question pertains to maintaining my garden.  I would also argue that installation and maintenance of sprinkler systems is an important part of landscaping.  That's my $.02.

Comment: that makes sense. It will be interesting to see where we place the boundaries. I think this one is probably on topic, but its the first one I've see that is borderline.

Comment: @wax-eagle - I agree.  No harm in asking.  Glad you brought it up.

Comment: +1 Agree with the sprinkler systems part especially for gardening. There are a lot of problems that can be associated with overhead sprinkler watering (increased chances of mold/mildew/fungus) versus, say, a soaker hose that waters roots and not foilage.