# Why is this off topic?

Tags: discussion, support

I posted [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/41774/garden-smells-of-dog-urine-due-to-no-drainage/41780#41780) yesterday and has since been marked as off topic, yet I fail to see why. It's about a garden/landscaping related issue that seems perfect for this SE. The issue of "urine smell" is secondary to the actual question being asked, as it's primarily about a drainage problem (as in, the same thing happens with rain water). I included this in case anyone had any suggestions for products or methods to use to help resolve situations where pet urine smells exist in the garden.

If this question is deemed as off-topic for this SE, can someone please point me to an SE where it's 100% on-topic?

Also, the linked [meta question](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/is-a-sprinkler-pest-question-on-topic) to explain the reason WHY it's off-topic actually suggests that "pest control" in the context of landscaping is on topic. While this is not about pest control in any way shape or form, the link is 100% unhelpful in explaining the reasons why kevinsky decided it was off topic.

Comment: @Kevinsky Why did you close this question, really? And why did you, in your explanation, link to the meta question that doesn't have anything to do with the original question??

Comment: I have suggested a minor edit to the question that I hope will allow it to be reopened.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with you, you want to improve your garden situation. This would fall in the category "garden or landscape planning and layout" from [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I don't know why it was closed, my guess is that the focus was too much on the dogs and not on the garden? If that was indeed the reason you can try SE [pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest that you edit the question.  Remove, or downplay, the reference to dogs and emphasize the drainage issue.

Editing a question will place it in the re-open review queue.  With luck the reviewers will reopen the question for you.